# get function returns None from Beautifulsoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to list all titles from a specific position in job page
for some reason when I apply the function on the Beautifulsoup object to get all the 'id's, it returns None. How do I remove result that contains None?

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from sys import exit
import time

job_name = "python"
html_text = requests.get(f"https://www.jobstreet.com.my/{job_name}-jobs/").text
web_html = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

def info(link):
    page_job = requests.get(f"https://www.jobstreet.com.my{link}").text
    web_html2 = BeautifulSoup(page_job, "lxml")
    position = web_html2.find("h1", class_="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21").text
    

    print(f"Position : {position}")


list_job = web_html.find("div", class_="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw67i _1hbhsw66e _1hbhsw69q _1hbhsw68m _1hbhsw6n _1hbhsw65a _1hbhsw6ga _1hbhsw6fy")
open_listjob = list_job.find('a', class_="jdlu994 jdlu996 jdlu999 y44q7i2 z1s6m00 z1s6m0f _1hbhsw6h")
for link in web_html.find_all('a', href=True):
    if '/en/job' in link['href']:
        temp_link=link.get('href')
        info(temp_link)
```

output:

```
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Internship for Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Project Implementation Engineer (Software Engineer)</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Fresh/Junior Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Lead Engineer - Cloud (Hybrid Working)</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Sofware Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Senior Python Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Robotics Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Python Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Data Scientist / Analyst</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">R&amp;D Software Developer (DevOps)</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Engineer (Junior)</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Developer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Engineer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Senior Software Programmer</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Data Scientist (AI Systems and Applications)</h1>
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Development Engineer</h1>
None
None
<h1 class="z1s6m00 _1hbhsw64y y44q7i0 y44q7il _1d0g9qk4 y44q7is y44q7i21">Software Engineer - Equipment Software Integration</h1>
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

expected output:

```
1. Position: Internship for Software Engineer
2. Position: Software Engineer
3: Position: Software Engineer
...
..
```

Comment: Due to the manner in which that page is constructed the constant class values you're using are unlikely to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to specify the class attributes especially as they're likely to change from time to time - i.e., they are not constant.

I suggest a different structure that includes multithreading for optimal performance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from threading import Thread

job_name = 'python'

url = f'https://www.jobstreet.com.my/{job_name}-jobs/'

def process(href):
    try:
        with requests.get(f'https://www.jobstreet.com.my{href}') as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
            if (h := soup.find('h1')):
                print(h.getText())
    except Exception:
        pass

def main():
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        threads = []
        soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
        for a in soup.find_all('a'):
            if (href := a['href']).startswith('/en/job'):
                threads.append(Thread(target=process, args=(href,)))
                threads[-1].start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Fresh/Junior Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Internship for Software Engineer
Robotics Software Engineer
Application Engineer (Software Systems)
Data Scientist / Analyst
Software Developer
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I would do:

```
def info(link):
    ...
    if position:
        print(position)
```

Comment: I receive error when print AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.  I have update expected outcome and new coding

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It looks perfectly fine to me.